# jQuery Resizable() UI Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

In general, **resizable()** works fine. Here is where I am getting into an issue.

1. I have a div that contains some resizable items that work fine (resizable() applied to them at some point).
2. user can save items for later view (the *innerHTML* of the div gets saved into a JavaScript array, then div gets cleared so they can do something else)
3. When items get placed back onto div (from array) -- I do a **$('#divname').append(arrayname[i]);** -- items are no longer resizable (although visually they have the resizable classes/handle on them)

Here is what I have tried so far (none of which have worked):

1. After append() line, I re-initialize the resizable -- **$('#items').resizable();**
2. After append() line, remove then re-add resizable -- **$('#items').resizable('destroy').resizable();**

Any help is appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - I figured out what to do to solve this.

Before saving/storing the **innerHTML** of the div (*as described in step #2 in my question*), I destroyed the 'resizable' state of any elements in there like this (*example selector*):

```
$('#divid .resizable_items').resizable('destroy');
```

***Then*** I stored the **innerHTML** of the div into the JavaScript array.

Next, when repopulating the div, I appended the array element and re-initialized the resizable items like so:

```
$('#divid').append(arrayname[i]);
$('#divid .resizable_items').resizable();
```

So the issue seems to have been that storing the innerHTML which contained resizable() items did not work when re-appending/adding/rendering them, but destroying the resizables BEFORE storing the innerHTML, and then re-initializing resizable() once they were put back, it all works properly.

So this **seems** to have addressed the issue - hope it helps.